# Store Prepared Statement mysqli_stmt_get_result in Session

Tags: php, session, prepared-statement

I am trying to store my prepared statement results in a session so that I can access this information (non-sensative) without tripping to the db every time the page is loaded.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['stored'])) {
   prepared Statement goes here...
   $_SESSION['form_structure'] = mysqli_stmt_get_result($db);
} else {
   $_SESSION['stored'] = $_SESSION['stored'];
}

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($_SESSION['stored'])) {
...do something
}
```

when the page first loads and it registers the session for the first time, everything works fine. When i load page for the second time and it skips the prepared statement and just re-asigns the session to the session, it fails. I get an error:

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in ... on line 495
```

line 495 is my while loop reference above. I am not sure why it is not working on re-load but on new load it works fine. I have checked the session using empty/isset and it is saying it's set. It's just throwing the error on re-load. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Except when the PHP Script terminates, Any open connections are CLOSED automagically

Comment: If you want to save prepared queries, you will need to write Stored Proceedures instead of preparing queries in script